# Poetry build has slow performance if a large number of files exist in the repostiory even if they are excluded

Tags: python-poetry

I'm using poetry with a node_modules folder in the directory tree. It is excluded in the pyproject.toml file and isn't included in the sdist and wheel. But it being present anywhere in the directory tree the build will take approximately 15 minutes, but if I delete the folder the build will take about 30 seconds. The node_modules folder is also in the .gitignore file and I've tried modifying the pyproject.toml file a few different ways but haven't found any solution. Is there a trick I need to know so it completely ignores this folder?

Comment: I've come across the same problem, but I also found nothing what helps. So I filed an issue here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7644